# Want to generate carousel with owl images in it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I want a hidden div on owl carousel. Please Help me . 
i am calling all css file from owl carousel . 
Here is my calling css file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css">
```

/owl-carousel/owl.theme.css">
/owl-carousel/owl.transitions.css">

Here is my calling JS file

```
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
```

/owl-carousel/active.js">

and i get up 
my HTML source file

```
    <div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel">
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/1170x300/42bdc2/FFFFFF"></div>
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/1170x400/42bdc2/FFFFFF"></div>
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/1170x500/42bdc2/FFFFFF"></div>
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/1170x200/42bdc2/FFFFFF"></div>
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/1170x500/42bdc2/FFFFFF"></div>
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/1170x250/42bdc2/FFFFFF"></div>
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/1170x350/42bdc2/FFFFFF"></div>
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/1170x300/42bdc2/FFFFFF"></div>
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/1170x100/42bdc2/FFFFFF"></div>
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/1170x500/42bdc2/FFFFFF"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Html Code Making use of slick.js**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.1/slick.min.css"/> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.1/slick.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.15/slick.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.15/slick.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app2.js"></script>
    <style>
    body {
    background-color: lightblue;
   }
   #slickslide {
       height: 200px;
       background: lightgray;
     }
     #content {
         margin: auto;
         padding: 20px;
         width: 80%;
     }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="demo"></div>
<div id=content>  
  <div id="slickslide" slick="">
    <div><h1>Test1</h1><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut. </p></div>
    <div><h1>Test2</h1><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut. </p></div>
    <div><h1>Test3</h1><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut. </p></div>
    <div><h1>Test4</h1><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut. </p></div>
    <div><h1>Test5</h1><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut. </p></div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#slickslide').slick({
         dots: true,
         infinite: true,
         speed: 300,
         autoplay:true,
         autoplaySpeed: 1000,
         slidesToShow: 1,
         slidesToScroll: 1
     });
 });
```

Comment: replace the div content with owl images